# What is the best way to broadcast messages to several netcore client application?

Tags: tcp, websocket, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-standard

I need to send json messages to one thousand dotnet core application simultaneously into the same network. Currently i use rest web api with self hosted kestrel server and i ask me if this is best solution. Does exists a self hosted message broker for dotnet core application or another solution?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here because it's primarily opinion-based. You'd be best off trying a solution then - if it doesn't suit your needs, asking for help on the specific part which you have issues with.

Comment: Did you have a look on SignalR [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/real-time)

Comment: SignalR Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: It seems that SignalR allows to send request from server to client (web client with javascript). Can I use it to send request server to server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Service Bus with Topic. You can send your message to one topic and subscribe N application to that topic to receive messages.

Each application can have its own subscription under topic. Find more information how to create topic and subscription lies [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions).

You can use Service Bus Explorer for local debugging and seeing the messages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to embed the message broker into my application. I cannot use Azure or RabbitMq or other.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose [signalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.2)

define your Hub

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
       public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
       {
          await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
       }
    }
}
```

Add SignalR in `StartUp`

```
 services.AddSignalR();

 app.UseSignalR(routes =>
 {
      routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
 });
```

Then define client side(dont forget to include js library `signalr.js`)

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().then(function(){
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

`SendMessage` is defined in Hub as method and server will listen for it. `ReceiveMessage` is listener on client side to show what server sends.

*all code from from* [signalR documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.2)